# Is there any way to use our own server for storage of data generated using PUBNUB api?

Tags: pubnub

I was using PUBNUB api for chat module in my product ,so I was curious that Is there any way that we can store chat data on own server?

Comment: Shubham, review my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868207/pubnub-chat-application-with-storage/30880242#30880242

Comment: Shubham, did the answers on the other SO post help? If so please indicate on that post and here.

Comment: ya Craig your answers are really helpful